# I want an mp3 file to be played when a button is pressed a certain amount of times in swift

Tags: swift, mp3

I am working on a tap counter app and I need a sound to be played every thousand clicks but I could not figure out how to play it after multiple clicks in swift. If possible could someone please provide the code necessary to do so. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Set up your mp3 file in an AVAudioPlayer, start a counter at zero, increment the counter when the button is pushed, play the sound and reset the counter to zero when the counter reaches 1000. Oh, and don't expect the good people of Stack Overflow to write your code for you. That just tends to attract down votes.

Comment: @Chris thank you I  am new to stack overflow so I didn't know. I am a beginner when it comes to swift which is why I asked for code.

Comment: Understood. If you break the problem down in to steps like I have above and then search the Internet (or Stack Overflow) for each step then you will find a wealth of information. Welcome to SO and Swift. Hope you have a lovely time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable as a counter = 0. Increment that counter (+= operator) every time the button is pressed. Also check to see if if counter == 1000, and if so, play MP3 and reset counter to zero.